# User information managment

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server

We are currently using a very old spreadsheet to store user information when newbies start.

Forename    Surname Department  Role (group)    Login Username  Login Password  Email Username  Email Password

We then use the information to create the user on Active Directory. When users leave we delete their accounts on AD but want to store their details encase they return in the future

Is there a free, open source, or cheap software to manage all these users

Comment: a database. SQLite comes to mind as a small, free way to do this. It would also be very easy to write a little gui wrapper for the database system using autoit (it has a built-in sqlite library and easy to manage gui features).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous client deployed this comprehensive solution to manage a 800-strong AD environment.

[User Management Resource Administration](http://www.tools4ever.com/products/user-management-resource-administrator/)

Not too sure if it fit your needs, or budget - you can check it out though. It's pretty cool when I saw them use it.

Comment: I have had a look, but i was thinking of something more simple and easy to use

Comment: How many users are you looking to manage?

Comment: 200 - 300 users at least

Comment: I need some more idea's, maybe something using SQL